# Eclipse gdb expression: what is shown in "default"?

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb

Stepping through C code in gdb using Eclipse, I noticed that for a variable `char* sval` gdb prints (in Expressions tab):

- Expression: sval
- Type: char*
- Value: 0x7fffd9d79840 "BIDPRICE"

However I know that the value should be something different (say, "BIDZSPD") because it was assigned a few lines above. Indeed, the value of `sval[3]` is 'Z', as expected.

Then I noticed the following in the expressions view, same as in mouse-over on a variable:

```
Name : sval
Details:0x7fffd9d79840 "BIDZSPD"
Default:0x7fffd9d79840 "BIDPRICE"
Decimal:140736848173120
Hex:0x7fffd9d79840
Binary:11111111111111111011001110101111001100001000000
Octal:03777773165714100
```

Looks like different representations of char pointer, but why Details is different from Default? Should I interpret "Default" as previous value? Why Default is shown as expression value, and not current value?

Comment: Could you share that part of the program, especially where sval was declared and changed. And the Eclipse version. Thanks.

Comment: @Olof I appreciate you offering help, but this has been resolved by full build. It was not obvious at first, but eventually I noticed that gdb info was lagging a few lines of code. This gave indication that something was out of sync. And yes, I should have commented on this question earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Heh. No worries. Glad that it got solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full build fixed it. This is one of the things one needs to keep in mind when working with C++: if things look really screwy (like gdb reporting different values by the same address), you have to bite the bullet and do a full build.